# Derive Taylor series for df

Tags: statistics, partial-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

I was trying to understand ito's lemma. When I came across the Taylor series expansion of $df(x)$.

$df(x) = f'(x) dx + (1/2!) f''(x) (dx)^2 + ...$

I searched everywhere for the derivation of this but couldn't find. So I tried it on my own.

$f(x)= f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + (1/2!) [f''(a)(x-a)^2] +...$

so if I take $d/dx$

$df(x)/dx = f'(a) + (1/2!) [f''(a)d(x-a)^2/dx] + ...$

Making it

$df(x)/dx = f'(a) + (1/2!) [f''(a) 2(x-a)] + (1/3!) [f''(a) 3(x-a)^2] +...$

Can someone help me with how to proceed from here?

Comment: $$\begin{align} df(x) & = f(x+dx) - f(x). \\ & = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {f^{(n)} (x)} {n!} (dx)^n - f(x). \\ & =  \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {f^{(n)} (x)} {n!} (dx)^n.\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi thanks. I understood this. But is it possible to arrive at the result from where I left off?

Comment: You have found the expansion of $f(x)$ about a point $a$ where it is differentiable infinitely many times which is not needed here as you can see from the expression of Ito's lemma. So you have to modify them accordingly. They are different looking forms of the same expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align} df(x) & = f(x+dx) - f(x). \\ & = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {f^{(n)} (x)} {n!} (dx)^n - f(x). \\ & =  \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {f^{(n)} (x)} {n!} (dx)^n.\end{align}